# Can I use Deja Dup with the SurDoc cloud service?

Tags: 12.04, backup, lxde, deja-dup

I have recently created an account in surdoc cloud(its a free account). I want to backup my home pc data to surdoc cloud using deja-dup backup. Can anyone tell me what changes should I make to 'Storage' section of deja-dup-preferences to solve the issue?

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS with lxde DE.

### Edit

As I told in comment, after executing `deja-dup-preferences`, there's section called *Storage*. In *Storage*, there's a subfield *Backup location* which has several options of which only *SSH*, *Windows Share* or *Custom Location* should be chosen. Of these which option should I choose and why?

Comment: After running `deja-dup-preferences`, I see a section _Storage_. In that section there is a subsection called _Backup location_ which is currently set to `Ubuntu One`, another subsection is _Folder_ which currently set to `deja-dup/_myPCname_`. Other options in _Backup location_ are: FTP, SSH, WebDAV, Windows Share, Custom Location. which option should I select?

Comment: Also when I login to my _SurDoc_ account, I see the connection is HTTPS. So I think FTP option in _Backup location_ is inappropriate. Now if I select SSH I get following new subsections: Server, Port, Folder, Username. In _Server_ I'm writing `data2e1.surdoc.net` as this is the site I'm seeing in my web browser. Is it correct and what values should I give to other fields?

Comment: www.surdoc.com dosen't use webDAV as after executing `sudo mount -t davfs https://www.surdoc.com/ /media/surdoc.com` and giving username and password, I get following output:`/sbin/mount.davfs: mounting failed; the server does not support WebDAV`. Do only _SSH_, _Windows Share_ or _Custom Location_ options remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SurDoc FAQ](https://www.surdoc.com/learn-more/faqs/):

> **Does SurDoc provide WebDAV or FTP access?**
>
> SurDoc doesn’t support WebDAV or FTP access at this time.

So, no.  Deja Dup cannot support SurDoc storage using standard protocols.  Looks like you need to use their Windows app under wine:

> **Is there a SurDoc client for Linux?**
>
> There’s no SurDoc client for Linux yet but our Windows client will run on recent versions of the Wine compatibility layer: http://www.winehq.org/